# pop-up shows when login succeed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile 1.4, and i have a login form. I want to show a popup when username and password are wrong and go to another page when succeeds. The problem is that popup is showing even when succeed, any time i click "login"

```
$user = isset($_POST['uName']) ? strtolower($_POST['uName']) : '';
$pass = isset($_POST['uPass']) ? $_POST['uPass'] : '';

if (!isset($logins[$user]) or $logins[$user] != $pass) {
    echo "<script language=Javascript>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#login-form').on('submit',function(e) {      
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#popup').popup({ overlayTheme: 'b' });
        $('#popup').popup('open');
    });
});
</script>";
} else {
    echo "<script language=Javascript>
document.location.href='flow.php';
</script>";
}

$logins = array(
    'username2' => 'password2',
    'username3' => 'password3',
);
?>

<div data-role="main" id="page-content-ajax" class="ui-content jqm-content jqm-fullwidth ">
     <div role="main" class="ui-content jqm-content">
            <form action="" id="login-form" method="POST" />
            <input name="uName" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
            <input name="uPass" type="password" />   
            <button type="submit" id="btn-login" class="ui-btn ui-btn-active ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-arrow-r" >Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
<div data-role="popup" id="popup" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="b" style="max-width:400px;">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
            <h1>Warning!</h1>
        </div>
        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            <h3 class="ui-title">Wrong username or password</h3>
            <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow">Ok</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: show your popup markup and it's location within page. Plus dont use `.ready()` in jQM.

Comment: I editet it. popup is after form div. even when i dont use .ready() it does the same

Comment: and url adds this #&ui-state=dialog when is shown dialog

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
if (!isset($logins[$user]) or $logins[$user] != $pass) {
```

to:

```
if (!isset($logins[$user]) || $logins[$user] != $pass) {
```

Comment: no again the same. when i just put an alert, it works, i think the problem is with poup

Comment: When i use popup yes it always goes at if and doesn't perform else. But with alert it goes at else condition when login succeeds